# Project references with microdata

Tags: microdata

I have a site where I need to list my projects from before. They are websites with name, URL, description, list of used technologies, and an image gallery.

I was searching for a schema for it on schema.org, but I was not able to find a fitting one. What itemscopes should I use?

Comment: Can you clarify what type of "projects" these are? Are you a software developer and trying to list client projects you've worked on in the past?

Comment: Actually I'm a student and these projects are school projects, but yes they are websites, and the page I'm working on needs to simulate what you have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good fit for what you need in the current available Schemas on http://schema.org.

What I'd do:

- Use http://schema.org/WebPage for your webpage definition, along with parts of http://schema.org/WebPageElement as needed.
- Use http://schema.org/Person for defining yourself
- Lastly for each project, I'd use what's already there for the parent `Creative Work` schema (http://schema.org/CreativeWork) since there is no sub-schema under it that fits for you.  I'd then just define attributes and values for `about`, `datePublished`, `author`, `headline`, `keywords`. Also define `editor`, `video`, `awards` and `publisher` if appropriate.